# Complex Input Impedance of Autotransformer with Complex Load

Tags: input-impedance, autotransformer

I am interested in the input impedance Zin of an autotransformer with coupling k and complex load Z1 as shown in the picture. Does anyone know how this can be calculated?

[image]

This is what I tried so far. However, a comparison with a simulation showed that my calculated result is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would approach this problem from first principles. I don't make any promises that I have not made an error in my algebra, but this is how I would approach the problem.

I made some slight renaming and selected current directions for my analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVG5bV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Note the polarity dots next to the inductors are indicate how the inductors are magnetically coupled. When the mutual magnetic field of the two inductors is changing, the EMF induced is of the same polarity on the dotted ends of the inductors.)

We will now write down some equations relating currents, voltages and impedances. Lower case letters represent instantaneous values. Upper case letters represent complex values.

$$I_{in} = I_1 + I_2$$

$$V_1 + V_2 = I_2Z_{load}$$

$$Z_{in} = \frac{V_1}{I_{in}}$$

and here are two that may not be as familiar

$$v_1 = L_1i_1'  - Mi_2'$$

$$v_2 = -L_2i_2' + Mi_1'$$

where \$M=k\sqrt{L_1L_2}\$

We can take the Laplace transforms of the last two equations to get

$$V_1(s) = sL_1I_1(s) - sMI_2(s)$$

$$V_2(s) = -sL_2I_2(s) + sMI_1(s)$$

And we can convert those to equations using complex impedances.

$$V_1(s) = X_1I_1(s) - X_MI_2(s)$$

$$V_2(s) = -X_2I_2(s) + X_MI_1(s)$$

where \$X_1 = sL_1\$, \$X_2 = sL_2\$, and \$X_M = sM\$.

We can also just drop the "(s)"s, to get

$$V_1 = X_1I_1 - X_MI_2$$

$$V_2 = -X_2I_2 + X_MI_1$$

If we substitute \$V_2 = I_2Z_{load}-V_1\$ into the second equation we get we get

$$I_2Z_{load}-V_1 = -X_2I_2 + X_MI_1$$

Rearranging, we get

$$V_1 = I_2Z_{load} + X_2I_2 - X_MI_1 = (Z_{load} + X_2)I_2 - X_MI_1$$

We can combine this with a previous equation for \$V_1\$, thus eliminating it.

$$V_1 = X_1I_1 - X_MI_2 = (Z_{load} + X_2)I_2 - X_MI_1$$

So

$$X_1I_1 + X_MI_1 = (Z_{load} + X_2)I_2 + X_MI_2$$

$$(X_1+X_M)I_1 = (Z_{load}+X_2+X_M)I_2$$

$$I_2 = \frac{X_1+X_M}{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M}I_1$$

This can now be substituted into \$V_1 = X_1I_1 - X_MI_2\$ to give

$$V_1 = X_1I_1 - X_M\frac{X_1+X_M}{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M}I_1 = \left(X_1 - X_M\frac{X_1+X_M}{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M}\right)I_1$$

$$V_1 = \left(\frac{X_1(Z_{load}+X_2+X_M)}{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M} - \frac{X_1X_M+X_M^2}{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M}\right)I_1$$
$$ = \left(\frac{X_1Z_{load}+X_1X_2+X_1X_M-(X_1X_M+X_M^2)}{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M}\right)I_1$$

$$V_1 = \left(\frac{X_1Z_{load}+X_1X_2+X_1X_M-X_1X_M-X_M^2}{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M}\right)I_1$$
$$= \left(\frac{X_1Z_{load}+X_1X_2-X_M^2}{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M}\right)I_1$$

So,

$$I_1 = \frac{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M}{X_1Z_{load}+X_1X_2-X_M^2}V_1$$

And

$$I_{in} = I_1 + I_2 = I_1 + \frac{X_1+X_M}{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M}I_1 = \frac{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M + X_1+X_M}{Z_{load}+X_2+X_M}I_1 $$
$$= \frac{Z_{load}+X_2+2X_M + X_1}{X_1Z_{load}+X_1X_2-X_M^2}V_1$$

From which we can finally conclude that

$$Z_{in} = \frac{V_1}{I_{in}} = \frac{X_1Z_{load}+X_1X_2-X_M^2}{Z_{load}+X_2+2X_M + X_1}$$

Letting \$X_2 = n^2X_1\$ we can get a perhaps more friendly form

$$Z_{in} = \frac{X_1Z_{load}+n^2X_1^2-k^2n^2X_1^2}{Z_{load}+n^2X_1+2knX_1 + X_1}=\frac{X_1Z_{load}+(1-k^2)n^2X_1^2}{Z_{load}+(n^2+1+2kn)X_1}$$

Although this is not a comprehensive check, if we set \$k=1\$ we get

$$Z_{in(k=1)} = \frac{X_1Z_{load}}{Z_{load}+(n+1)^2X_1} = X_1 || \frac{Z_{load}}{(n+1)^2}$$

which looks reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer! Ich checked your solution with my simulation, a perfect match! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. It is easy for me to drop and exponent, or make some other silly mistake when doing algebra like this, so unless I check and recheck and recheck, I worry about mistakes.